# How to let active model serializer automatically convert enum attribute to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [ :active, :inactive ]
end
```

By default the active model serializer serializes `User` object's `status` attribute to a string, either `"active"` or `"inactive"`, but I would like it to be integer `0` or `1`. To accomplish so, I have to do this manually:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :status
  def status
    object.status_before_type_cast  # get integer
    # or User.statuses[object.status], the same thing
  end
end
```

This is a bit ugly because **I have to write code for each enum attribute for each active model class**. Is there any option to do this once?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the enum index value like a hash

```
User.statuses[:active]
=> 0
User.statuses[:inactive]
=> 1
```

I hope this is what you looking for

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I was aware of this, but I was looking for an option that lets AMS automatically do this, otherwise there would be a method for each enum attribute inside the serializer definition, like the `status` in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

> enum status: { active: 0, inactive: 1 }

```
Model.statuses # Pluralized version of the enum attribute name
```

That returns a hash like:

> => {"active"=>0, "inactive"=>1}

You can then use the status value from an instance of the Model class to access the integer value for that instance:

```
my_model = Model.find(123)

Model.statuses[my_model.status] # Returns the integer value
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/enumerated-types-with-activerecord-and-postgresql/

Comment: This does not solve the problem of having to write code for each enum attribute for each active model class in its serializer class.